# Python REST decoding the results of FileReader::readAsDataURL

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, filereader

I am using Python / Django to process a REST request - one of the elements in the REST is the Data URI of a file to upload. It looks like everything is fine (js captures the file and builds the json correctly), but when I decode the file on the server and write the binary to disk it is different.

I am new to python/django from a .NET and Java background - any help is more than appreciated.  Thank you

HTML input control

```
<input type="file" class="col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 0px" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().attachment = this.files[0]; angular.element(this).scope().$digest();"/>
```

Add Image from my angular JS controller

```
$scope.addImage = function () {
    var attachment = $scope.attachment
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        $scope.public_file = $scope.public_files.concat({filename: attachment.name, data: fr.result})
        $scope.$digest()
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(attachment);
}
```

Parsing on the server

```
def getData(uri):
    head, data = uri.split(',')

    decoded =data.decode('base64','strict');
    # decoded base64.b64decode(data)
    return decoded


  def create(self, request):
        data = getData(request['public_files'])

        with open(file_path, 'w+') as f:
            f.write(data)

        return super(UpdatingIdeasViewSet, self).create(request)
```

---

Comparing console.log(fr.result) on the client with request['public_files'] on the server yields the same string.  It must be a base64 decoding issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file for binary write?

```
   with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(data)
```